# Reading mfc resource dll content

Tags: c#, c++, dll, mfc, localization

As part of my automation activity, I want to compare resource dll content of two different languages.i.e. Following content of resource in english:

```
 IDD_DIALOG_M DIALOGEX 0, 0, 474, 278 STYLE DS_SETFONT | DS_FIXEDSYS |
 WS_CHILD | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU CAPTION "I AM DIALOG" FONT 8, "MS
 Shell Dlg", 400, 0, 0x1 BEGIN  END
```

In Chinese resource content become:

```
 IDD_DIALOG_M DIALOGEX 0, 0, 474, 278 STYLE DS_SETFONT | DS_FIXEDSYS |
 WS_CHILD | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU CAPTION "我是DIALOG" FONT 8, "MS
 Shell Dlg", 400, 0, 0x1 BEGIN  END
```

I will write a tool in C# or any specific language and will provide two localize dll as input. A tool will compare two resources and if match found then two dlls are passed.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @AndrejBratoz question is compare of two different language resource DLL.

Comment: That isn't a question; it's a task.

Comment: @WhozCraig i know it's a task and will do that but need initial information to compare those two dll. Remaining will do.

Comment: It's just not clear what you're asking. What does 'compare resource dll' mean? Compare the properties of each resource? When are two resources 'equal' in your scenario? What are you asking - how to enumerate resources, how to get resource details, what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you want to check the existence of all resource components (controls) of a dialog. and if they have the correct styles.

Writing this in C# may be more complicated than writing this stuff in C++ ;)

1. For DLL1 Call EnumResourceTypes, EnumResourceNames, EnumResourceLanguages to enumerate all the resources.
2. Call FindResource for DLL2 to fnd the resource with the same ID
3. List item. Get pointers to the resource of both DLLs
4. According the type of the dialog you have pointers to [DLGTEMPLATEEX](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645398%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) or [DLGTEMPLATE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645394%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) (see signature in first WORD)
5. Now walk over all controls and compare the types and IDs, you have now either [DLGITEMTEMPLATEEX](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645389(v=vs.85).aspx) or [DLGITEMTEMPLATE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644997(v=vs.85).aspx) elements.

Comparing this is a little bit tricky, because all items are variable size.

I have the same in a class directly in my application and it is only executed in the debug version. So in the alpha and beta tests we get asserts immediately when resources don't behave as expected.

It makes sense to ignore the positions of the control when you check it. But important are the class names and the styles (style/exStyle member), because they have deep impact on the behavior of the controls.

Just a hint: We use a special translation program named [RC-WinTrans](http://www.schaudin.com). With this tool we translate all RC files from one language into a second. And we get always correct formatted RC files and can easily create the corresponding satellite DLLs.